# How can I performance/ping test an Azure application relying on Oauth2 authentication flow?

Tags: node.js, azure, oauth-2.0, performance-testing, azure-application-insights

I have an Azure-hosted web application with Azure AD Oauth2 authentication flow. The Oauth2 flow exists as a manual implementation but it will soon rely on Passport Azure AD.

Because of the authentication process, I cannot quickly use Azure's built-in performance testing capabilities or set up ping tests.

What solutions exist to do cloud-based performance and availability testing for such an application?

Answer (score 0):

If your tokens live long enough (as per [Configurable Token Lifetimes in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes))) it can be 1 day, you can just generate as many tokens as you require and add the relevant [Authorization headers](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer.html) for each virtual user.

Alternatively I would recommend checking out [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) article which highlights several approaches of bypassing OAuth challenges during performance testing.